# Can we change a JLabel from another class in java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am new to java and I am trying to use a `JLabel` and a `JButton`.  My problem is that I can't change the `JLabel` in the `actionPerformed()` method. It cannot find the variable `nbr`. Please help :(

```java
package com.test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main(){
        super("Test");
        setSize(640, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        add(button1);
        JLabel nbr = new JLabel(x);
        add(nbr);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x++;
        nbr.setText(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it a field rather than a local variable. Note that, unlike what your question title says, you have a single class here. There is no other class.

Comment: You can also pass this label as parameter to your method

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are accessing a variable that is in different and limited scope. In your case your `nbr` is defined in your `Main()` function and is limited only to that scope. If you want to access it you have to make it global, means you have to declare it in your class.

**Example:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    int x = 0;
    private JLabel nbr; // declare a global variable

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main(){
        super("Test");
        nbr = new JLabel(); // initialize here...

        setSize(640, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        add(button1);
        nbr.setText(x); // set text to that variable here...
        add(nbr);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x++;
        nbr.setText(x);
    }
}
```

*P.s: Check for any syntax errors, I wrote this without testing. :)*

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to make `nbr` a member of class `Main` but keep it as a local variable in the class constructor, you can still use the *Swing* API to update the `JLabel` text from the `actionPerformed()` method. Sample code below. Note that both the `JLabel` constructor and its `setText()` method require a `String` argument and not a `int` argument, hence the code you posted does not compile. I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In any case, I have fixed that error in the below code.

```java
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main(){
        super("Test");
        setSize(640, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        add(button1);
        JLabel nbr = new JLabel(String.valueOf(x));
        add(nbr);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x++;
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        Component[] cmpts = contentPane.getComponents();
        for (Component cmpt : cmpts) {
            if (cmpt instanceof JLabel) {
                JLabel nbr = (JLabel) cmpt;
                nbr.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @marchamamji For learning _Swing_, I recommend the tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Main().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main(){
        super("Test");
        setSize(640, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        final JLabel  nbr     = new JLabel("0");
        add(button1);
        add(nbr);

        final AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();

        button1.addActionListener(e -> {
            nbr.setText("" + x.incrementAndGet());
        });
    }
}
```